# How can tzdata.zi file can be identified not as a .zi file Unambiguously?

Tags: zip, mime-types, magic-numbers, zoneinfo, file-header

I've got the tzdata.zi file (appears under the mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 docker image).
From what I know it's a "zone info" file.
Unfortunately it got the same extension of .zi (which is also equivalent to zip file).
.zip file can be recognized by its [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) magic number (50 4B 03 04) from its signature.
But what about tzdata.zi, what is his magic number should I be looking for?
The reason I'm looking for a magic number is to identify Unambiguously that the file isn't a .zip file, since there is a possibility of a corrupted .zi files that also will have an issue with their signature.